# Haskell cannot define function as part of record?

Tags: haskell, record

I would like to define a data type that is a record with one function named f:

`data A = A { f :: Int -> Int }`

and I would like to create an instance:

`A {f x = x * 2 }`

However: this gives a syntax error:

`error: parse error on input ‘x’`

Comment: Try `A {f = \x -> x * 2 }`.

Comment: That works, but I don't understand why it can't be done in the way above.

Comment: The [Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#record-construction) defines record construction as requiring that each field name is written exactly as defined, and there can't be anything but whitespace between `k` and `=` in `k = v`. I guess they just didn't think of it or didn't think it was worth the effort of defining.

Comment: With the `RecordWildCards` extension you can also use `let f x = x * 2 in A{..}` but IMO it's simpler to use a lambda as Alec suggested. The syntax could allow your form, which makes sense. Probably, since you can't define arbitrary identifiers inside `A{}`, the Haskell designers choose a custom syntax rather than re-using the one for definitions.

Comment: Are you asking about "why" as in "why was haskell chosen to be written this way?" or, "why" as in "what part of the haskell spec says that this can't be done"?

Answer (score 0):

The following is the grammar for constructions using field labels.

```
aexp    →   qcon { fbind1 , … , fbindn }        (labeled construction, n ≥ 0)
fbind   →   qvar = exp
```

Note that `qcon` is a constructor syntax, `qvar` is a variable syntax, and `exp` is an expression syntax.

The reason `A {f x = x * 2}` does not work therefore is because it is invalid syntax. A syntax that is valid and that is probably what you want is `A {f = \x -> x * 2}`. Alternatively, `A {f = (* 2)}`, `A {f = (2 *)}`, or `A {f = (*) 2}`.

Construction using field labels operates like named parameters. Given a data type definition such as

```
data Person = Person { name :: String, age :: Int }
```

The expression

```
Person { age = 65, name = "Wilbur Suidae" }
```

Means

```
Person "Wilbur Suidae" 65
```

That is, the constructor arguments are ordered to match the order of fields according to the constructor definition.

The expression

```
Person { age = 65 }
```

Means

```
Person undefined 65
```

That is, if a field is not explicitly assigned a value it is implicitly assigned the value `undefined`.

#### References

- [*Construction Using Field Labels*, § 3.15.2, Haskell Report 2010](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-520003.15.2)